# How to write an algorithm that mimics a Calculator using Immediate Execution

Tags: swift, algorithm

I'm hoping someone could help me fix a bug in my calculator that I dont know how to get around.

For starters, I'm making a little program that models a calculator using immediate execution. As an overview, I had to dig through the internet to find out how immediate execution works for calculators so here's an explanation.

> Traditional scientific calculators that respond immediately to key presses have an X and a Y register. The X register is hidden and the Y register appears on the display. When you enter a value it is shifted into the Y register. If you press a binary operator key like + or * the value in the Y register is copied into the X register, the operation is stored, and the Y register is set to accept a new entry. If you then press another binary operator key then the X and Y registers are combined using the stored pending operator, the result is placed in the X register, the key press is stored as a new pending operator, and the Y register is reset to accept a new entry. There are variations around this for the = key (a no-op), for example. [Citation](https://www.eevblog.com/forum/microcontrollers/algebraic-calculator-algorithm/)

So far, I have implemented this in Swift using a superclass (AbstractCalculator) and a subclass of it (AbstractBinaryCalculator)

```
open class AbstractCalculator {

    public var _currentOperator : String = ""
    public var _currentNumberEnteredIn : String = ""

    public init() {}

    /**
     Inputs a single digit into the current number being entered
     - Parameter digit: A single digit
     */
    open func inputDigit(_ digit : Character) {
        self._currentNumberEnteredIn += String(digit)
    }
    
    open func inputEqualsSign() {
        fatalError("Need to override in subclasses")
    }
            
    open func inputOperator(_ calculatorOperator : String) {
        fatalError("Need to override in subclasses")
    }


}



open class AbstractBinaryCalculator : AbstractCalculator {

    public var _operatorDictionary = [String : ((String, String) -> String)]()

    public var _accumulatedResult : String = ""
    
    open override func inputDigit(_ digit: Character) {
        self._currentNumberEnteredIn += String(digit)
    }

    open func _saveCurrentNumberToAccumulatedResultIfNeeded() {
        if self._accumulatedResult.isEmpty {
            self._accumulatedResult = self._currentNumberEnteredIn
        }
    }

    open override func inputOperator(_ calculatorOperator: String) {
        if canPerformCalculation() {
            self._performCalculationAndSetAccumulatedResult()
        }
        self._currentOperator = calculatorOperator
        self._saveCurrentNumberToAccumulatedResultIfNeeded()
        self._currentNumberEnteredIn = ""
    }

    open override func inputEqualsSign() {
        if canPerformCalculation() {
            self._performCalculationAndSetAccumulatedResult()
        }
    }

    public func canPerformCalculation() -> Bool {
        let hasAccumulatedResult = !self._accumulatedResult.isEmpty
        let hasCurrentOperator = !self._currentOperator.isEmpty
        let isCurrentNumberEntered = !self._currentNumberEnteredIn.isEmpty
        return (hasAccumulatedResult && hasCurrentOperator && isCurrentNumberEntered)
    }

    open func _performCalculationAndSetAccumulatedResult() {
        let result = getResultUsingCurrentFunctionOnAccumulatedResultAndCurrentNumber()
        self._accumulatedResult = result
    }

    public func getResultUsingCurrentFunctionOnAccumulatedResultAndCurrentNumber() -> String {
        let function = getMathOperatorFunction()
        let currentNumberEnteredIn = self._currentNumberEnteredIn
        let accumulatedResult = self._accumulatedResult
        let result = function(accumulatedResult, currentNumberEnteredIn)
        return result
    }

    public func getMathOperatorFunction() -> (String, String) -> String {
        let mathOperator = self._currentOperator
        let function = self._operatorDictionary[mathOperator]!
        return function
    }

    /**
     Adds a new function to the calculator.
     - Parameter operatorFunction: An AbstractCalculatorOperator object
     */
    public func addOperatorFunction(_ operatorFunction : AbstractBinaryCalculatorOperator) {
        let mathOperator = operatorFunction.getOperatorSymbol()
        let function = operatorFunction.getFunction()
        self.addOperatorFunction(mathOperator, function: function)
    }

    /**
     Adds a new function to the calculator.
     - Parameter operatorSymbol: The symbol for the operator (+,-,% etc)
     - Parameter function: The function that will perform logic.
     */
    public func addOperatorFunction(_ operatorSymbol : String, function : @escaping (String, 
String) -> String) {
        self._listOfMathOperators.append(operatorSymbol)
        self._operatorDictionary[operatorSymbol] = function
    }


}
```

And to test out the calculators' functionality and test I made a small simple subclass of AbstractBinaryCalculator called IntegerCalculator.

```
public class IntegerCalculator : AbstractBinaryCalculator {

    public override init() {
        super.init()
        self.addOperatorFunction("+", function: self.add(number1:number2:))
        self.addOperatorFunction("-", function: self.subtract(number1:number2:))
        self.addOperatorFunction("*", function: self.multiply(number1:number2:))
    }
    
    private func add(number1 : String, number2 : String) -> String {
        let result = Int(number1)! + Int(number2)!
        return String(result)
    }

    private func subtract(number1 : String, number2 : String) -> String {
        let result = Int(number1)! - Int(number2)!
        return String(result)
    }

    private func multiply(number1 : String, number2 : String) -> String {
        let result = Int(number1)! * Int(number2)!
        return String(result)
    }

}
```

I then began to test out the code by running tests and all of them passed until I got to "testCalculation9" where I just don't know how to fix it. Can someone help me fix this bug?

```
import XCTest
@testable import AbstractCalculator

final class AbstractCalculatorTests: XCTestCase {


func testCalculation1() throws {
    
    let intCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    
    XCTAssertEqual(intCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "", "Incorrect")
    
    
}

func testCalculation2() throws {
    let integerCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "2", "Incorrect")

    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._accumulatedResult, "2", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentOperator, "+", "Incorrect")
}

func testCalculation3() throws {
    let integerCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("5")

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "5", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._accumulatedResult, "2", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentOperator, "+", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertTrue(integerCalculator.canPerformCalculation())
}

func testCalculation4() throws {
    let integerCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("5")
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "5", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._accumulatedResult, "7", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentOperator, "+", "Incorrect")
}

func testCalculation5() throws {
    let integerCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("5")
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "5", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._accumulatedResult, "12", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentOperator, "+", "Incorrect")
}

func testCalculation6() throws {
    let integerCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("*")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "2", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._accumulatedResult, "16", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentOperator, "*", "Incorrect")
}

func testCalculation7() throws {
    let integerCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("7")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("*")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("5")
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "5", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._accumulatedResult, "23", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentOperator, "+", "Incorrect")

    //Need setting for pemdas complient and non pemdas compliment.

}

func testCalculation8() throws {
    let integerCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("7")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("*")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("5")
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "5", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._accumulatedResult, "28", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentOperator, "+", "Incorrect")

    //Need setting for pemdas complient and non pemdas compliment.

}

func testCalculation9() throws {
    let integerCalculator = IntegerCalculator()
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("7")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("*")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("2")
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("5")
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()
    integerCalculator.inputOperator("+")
    integerCalculator.inputDigit("9")
    integerCalculator.inputEqualsSign()

    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentNumberEnteredIn, "9", "Incorrect")
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._accumulatedResult, "32", "Incorrect") //XCTAssertEqual failed: ("37") is not equal to ("32") 
    XCTAssertEqual(integerCalculator._currentOperator, "+", "Incorrect")

    

}


}
```

Comment: Asking to find a bug is not an appropriate question for this website. Asking to find a bug is a non-minimal question. A [minimal question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) can't be re-arranged to have less code while still reproducing the bug, so this means that all the code example is an essential part of the bug. Real-world example code won't be ***perfectly*** minimal, but close enough that basically everything will be essential to the bug.

Comment: Moreover, asking others to find a bug for you is either avoiding [learning how to debug](https://markheath.net/post/effective-debugging-with-divide-and-conquer), or - even worse - is just asking volunteers to do ***your*** work ***for*** you (and it's not exactly interesting work). Please read stackoverflow's guide on [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: I disagree with the critique made by the preceding comments.

Comment: I think it's because `inputEqualsSign()` performs the calculation of adding 5 to the result, but then `inputOperator("+")` (right after) performs the calculation of adding 5 _again_, which is why you get 37 instead of the expected 32.

Comment: @matt, I'm open to changing my mind. I see you've got a tonne of experience on the website. May I ask why?

Comment: @Elliott the question asked here wasn't "i have a bug, can you find it?", the question was why isn't testCalculation9 returning the expected result?  It is still a debugging failure - I know I would have put in a breakpoint, and stepped through the test case, checking the accumulation at each step so that I could see exactly which operation was doing the wrong thing, but it feels like a reasonable question